# imap_num_msg doesn't return correct amount

Tags: php, imap, php-imap

So I go to `/home/myname/Maildir/new` and I see three files in that folder.

In PHP I do `imap_num_msg(imap_open("{localhost:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "myname", "mypass"))` and I get 1 as the output.

Shouldn't the numbers be the same?

I do `sendmail myname@localhost < email.txt` on the CLI and the message appears in `/home/myname/Maildir/new` and yet `imap_num_msg` doesn't see it.

Comment: Have you connected an IMAP client (like Thunderbird) to it to see what it sees?

Comment: It was able to connect just fine - it's just that the server wasn't setup correctly. It was setup to expect emails in the mbox format instead of the mailbox format.